# How to find bottleneck in slow rails 3/ruby2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization, profiling, spree

How can I find out what's causing slowness in a rails application?
Here's some info pertaining to my particular case:

- I want to use use ujs with remote: true to avoid the need for a react or angular frontend, but http responses take way too long, sometimes over a second to render just a 'render :text => "hello"'
- the slowness is more visible in the admin section of the site, part of it is Spree Admin code
- Using Rails 3.2.22.5 , ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)
- Some kind of rack proxying is implemented when a request matches a regex, but the page I'm experiencing slowness is not a proxied page
- List item
- We're not using heroku, a hosting company called reinteractive
- Ideally I would like to get a Ujs remote:true .js.erb to come to the browser within half a second - or the closest - for a seamless user experience

Are there any ruby measurement tools that can help me, I would like to know

- Is the slowdown due to too much memory / paging
- Is there a cpu intensive def being executed?
- If a hello world page takes 3 seconds to GET, what number of seconds was spent on what portions/functions of the rails stack.

Comment: I'd install newrelic (or any other perf monitoring) - it may show you the causes. You can also use rack miniprofiler wih a flamegraph

Comment: newrelic is a good one. You can run it on your local computer and you don't have to pay for it.If you want more fancy stats then you should pay for it.